# Remove Quote or Comma Conditionally

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data like this:

```
0001,"Smith",20170112,"17 Long Lane Yorks YO12 1XT" 
0002,"Brown""Mr",201170112,"12 High St, Lincs, DN17 5ET"
```

I need a macro to remove any quotes that are NOT next to a comma and any commas NOT next to a quote.

ie output would be:

```
0001,"Smith",20170112,"17 Long Lane Yorks YO12 1XT" 
0002,"Brown Mr",201170112,"12 High St Lincs DN17 5ET"
```

I haven't got any ideas how to do this, is it possible and if so please show an example of the VBA.

The data is several hundred lines long so this will be a big help!

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your rules do indicate why the result shows a space between Brown and Mr.  If you remove those quotes, there is no space left.

Answer (score 2):

My non-technical approach:

- Replace `,"` and `",` with different symbols that you know are not in your data. e.g. `¬|` and `|¬`
- Replace remaining `"` and `,` with nothing (i.e. remove all of them)
- Replace your placeholders ( `¬|` `|¬`) with `,"` and `",` .

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern of input strings contain only `""` and `,` to be removed to meet your requirement. Just use the below formula as in the image, and drag it down through the complete range.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,""""""," "),", "," ")
```

[image]